# I want to make my terrain to delete after the camera moves past. How do I do that?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I can't seem to destroy prefabs after the camera moves past. Why not?

```
var cam : Rigidbody2D;
var terrain = GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);

function Update ()
{
    if (terrain.position.x <= cam.position.x - 5)
    {
        Destroy(this.GameObject);
    }
}
```

That is the deletion script. My terrain is endlessly spawning, what do I do? Its attached to every prefab.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The camera in the inspector is not set, so I'd assume you're getting some `NullReferenceExceptions` at runtime.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You have 'cam' which is a Rigidbody2D in your case. Are you trying to access Camera.main?

Comment: I set the camera, but its still not deleting the previous prefabs.

Comment: In fact, when I add the Main Camera to the prefab in the cam variable spot, when I drag the object into the prefab, that goes away. Why is that?